# Permutation/Combinations of Multiple Arrays / Cartesian product generation in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an example of 4 arrays describing the

```
let arrColor = ["red","green","blue"]
let arrSize = ["L","M"]
let arrMaterial = ["Cotton","polyester"]
let arrstyle = ["Eastern","Western"]
```

I need all the combinations of products possible from these arrays.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This concept is called the Cartesian product generation. We can use the following code from [here](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Swift) to do this

```
let arrColor = ["red","green","blue"]
let arrSize = ["L","M"]
let arrMaterial = ["Cotton","polyester"]
let arrstyle = ["Eastern","Western"]


func + <T>(el: T, arr: [T]) -> [T] {
    var ret = arr
    ret.insert(el, at: 0)
    return ret
}

func cartesianProduct<T>(_ arrays: [T]...) -> [[T]] {
    guard let head = arrays.first else {
        return []
    }
    let first = Array(head)
    func pel(
        _ el: T,
        _ ll: [[T]],
        _ a: [[T]] = []
        ) -> [[T]] {
        switch ll.count {
        case 0:
            return a.reversed()
        case _:
            let tail = Array(ll.dropFirst())
            let head = ll.first!

            return pel(el, tail, el + head + a)
        }
    }
    return arrays.reversed()
        .reduce([first], {res, el in el.flatMap({ pel($0, res) }) })
        .map({ $0.dropLast(first.count) })
}

let arrResult = cartesianProduct(arrColor,arrSize,arrMaterial,arrstyle)
print(arrResult)
```

Output :

```
[["red", "L", "Cotton", "Eastern"], ["red", "L", "Cotton", "Western"], ["red", "L", "polyester", "Eastern"], ["red", "L", "polyester", "Western"], ["red", "M", "Cotton", "Eastern"], ["red", "M", "Cotton", "Western"], ["red", "M", "polyester", "Eastern"], ["red", "M", "polyester", "Western"], 
["green", "L", "Cotton", "Eastern"], ["green", "L", "Cotton", "Western"], ["green", "L", "polyester", "Eastern"], ["green", "L", "polyester", "Western"], ["green", "M", "Cotton", "Eastern"], ["green", "M", "Cotton", "Western"], ["green", "M", "polyester", "Eastern"], ["green", "M", "polyester", "Western"], 
["blue", "L", "Cotton", "Eastern"], ["blue", "L", "Cotton", "Western"], ["blue", "L", "polyester", "Eastern"], ["blue", "L", "polyester", "Western"], ["blue", "M", "Cotton", "Eastern"], ["blue", "M", "Cotton", "Western"], ["blue", "M", "polyester", "Eastern"], ["blue", "M", "polyester", "Western"]]
```

Comment: To improve this answer I think you should have a struct/class Product with 4 properties corresponding to the arrays and then you map the result from an array of arrays to an array of Product

Comment: This is great!  Thank you.  Will you please explain your variable names?

Comment: This perform very slowly when having hundred of possible combinations. This solution works much faster : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56178470/570278